# 12.04.4 hangs at install

Tags: 12.04, system-installation

I am trying to install 12.04.4 on a Dell Precision M70 laptop. I wiped the disk clean and established 3 partitions - one formatted for root, one for swap and one NTFS. All are at least 30 Gig. I have tried installing from a CD but it always hangs without getting far. I created a bootable USB stick and was able to get quite a way with it. It appears that the system is about 2/3 installed and says it is currently installing system but no progress was made overnight. I have gotten to this same point twice. There is no error message - just no progress. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like corrupted USB image, maybe you can try to `dd` it again or to download it again.

Also, it may be bad hardware, try to run Live session Ubuntu from USB to try it out.